# How can I write to a text file reliably from Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to write to a text file.  I'm doing a few of these:

```
MyFile1 = "C:\outputFromExcel1.txt"
fnum1 = FreeFile()
Open MyFile1 For Output As fnum1
```

and then writing to them like this:

```
Print #fnum1, text
```

All variables in the above are declared just with `Dim`.  I'm writing hundreds of lines to the files and, very rarely, lines are being truncated -- i.e. the ends are being chopped off.  Is there a better way to write to a file in Excel VBA?

**EDIT:** I've just realized that it's always the last lines to be written that are truncated.  So I guess I need to close or flush the files somehow?

Comment: Are you closing the file after you're finished writing to it?  The close should flush the last lines to disk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Close #fnum1` to close the file handle and it should flush the remaining buffer contents.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should be closing the files with the `Close` method. I'm not sure if that's what causing the problems but you should be doing that either way.

If you're doing a lot of filehandling in your VBA code it might be worth looking at using FSO (FileSystemObject), I think it was originally for letting VBScript do file processing, but I prefer it to both VB6s and VBAs built in file handling.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details (and there's a big sample showing off how to do most things you need in one of those pages as well).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writing the text to a different sheet (or a different workbook) and then using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\MyFile.txt", FileFormat:=xlText
```

Not sure if this would give you better results (in terms of performance and/or formatting), but perhaps worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Just a necro solution: I have found the `Close #1` method to still leave a truncated file. Instead, or in addition to, use the `Application.Quit` for Excel to close Excel. This flushes the cache and completes the write to the text file.